# Index out of bound despite higher than lbound and lower than ubound

Tags: excel, vba

I copied the quicksort implementation below from Wikibooks (Author: John Green). I added a Little wrapper to test it. However, the execution Fails with an index out of bound error, which doesn't seem to make sense.

Direct Input Shows at breakpoint the following proper Output:

```
?UBound(VA_array)
 7 
?V_Low1
 1 
?V_High1
 7 

?(V_Low1 + V_High1) / 2
 4 
?dbgEchoVarType(VarType(VA_array))
vbArray: Array of type vbVariant: (used only with array of variants)
```

The latter is just a function to turn VarType into string. Type seems fine.

```
Public Sub sortThis()
    Dim r() As Variant
    r = Selection.Value2
    Debug.Print ("Selected Range: " & getRngAddress(Selection))
    Call QuickSort(r)
    Selection.Value2 = r
End Sub

Sub QuickSort(ByRef VA_array(), Optional V_Low1, Optional V_High1)
    Dim V_Low2 As Long, V_High2 As Long
    Dim V_val1 As Variant, V_val2 As Variant
    If IsMissing(V_Low1) Then V_Low1 = LBound(VA_array, 1)
    If IsMissing(V_High1) Then V_High1 = UBound(VA_array, 1)
    Debug.Print ("qs: Low1: " & V_Low1 & " / V_High1: " & V_High1)
    V_Low2 = V_Low1
    V_High2 = V_High1
    V_val1 = VA_array((V_Low1 + V_High1) / 2)
    While (V_Low2 <= V_High2)
        While (VA_array(V_Low2) < V_val1 And V_Low2 < V_High1)
            V_Low2 = V_Low2 + 1
        Wend
        While (VA_array(V_High2) > V_val1 And V_High2 > V_Low1)
            V_High2 = V_High2 - 1
        Wend
        If (V_Low2 <= V_High2) Then
            V_val2 = VA_array(V_Low2)
            VA_array(V_Low2) = VA_array(V_High2)
            VA_array(V_High2) = V_val2
            V_Low2 = V_Low2 + 1
            V_High2 = V_High2 - 1
        End If
    Wend
    If (V_High2 > V_Low1) Then Call QuickSort(VA_array, V_Low1, V_High2)
    If (V_Low2 < V_High1) Then Call QuickSort(VA_array, V_Low2, V_High1)
End Sub
```

The Selection contains 7 cells in one column, each containing a constant integer value.

I do not understand why 4 is considered an out of bound index.
The debug message in the above code Shows, that the code Fails on first call, not any successive calls.

What's wrong?

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: Your array is 2-dimensional not 1.

Comment: @Rory, that's exactly what I was thinking. Wasn't sure though as OP is getting the bounds of a 2 dimensional array but assignment is of single dimensional array

Comment: This line is throwing the Array:```V_val1 = VA_array((V_Low1 + V_High1) / 2)

Comment: Why is the Array two dimensional? The range is just one column wide.

Comment: When you assign a multi-cell range to an array like that, it is *always* 2 dimensional. So you would have to use `V_val1 = VA_array((V_Low1 + V_High1) / 2, 1)`

Comment: Nit: `If (V_Low2 <= V_High2) Then` - no point in swapping if they're equal.